# How to stream an .pls audio file in android 2.2

Tags: android, audio-streaming, pls-file

I am trying to play an .pls file (available at http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/listen.pls) in android 2.2. But it isn't working. Playing MP3 works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method for launching audio player on Android from web page for streaming media](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987597/method-for-launching-audio-player-on-android-from-web-page-for-streaming-media)

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support the `.pls` format. [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 1):

A `pls` or a [playlist file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_%28file_format%29) is basically a text file with the path of each track in each entry. Kind of like an `.ini` file. Take a look at the WP entry.

I don't think the inbuilt `MediaPlayer` supports these formats, so you'll have to download the file and parse the file and play the actual mp3's one by one.

Comment: @HARIDASS, I suggest you make (or search) a pls parser and implement a Playlist logic in your code. I don't have any example, sorry.